# Problems in my simple chat program

Tags: batch-file

I made a simple batch chat that write the message to an txt file.
I need help with print the file every time it changed and with hidding output.
I used the ***type, delay and cls*** to print the file but it didnt work, it didnt printed the file.

launcher.bat:

```
start cmd /k 
call room.bat
call chat.bat
```

[using the launcher photo](http://postimg.org/image/6kpjn52k1/)

room.bat(the problem):

```
:chat1
cls
TYPE room.txt
timeout /t 0.5
goto chat1
```

chat.bat(working but show extra info about the os and the file):

```
@echo off
cls
set D=%Date%
cls
echo enter your name
SET /P name=[name]
pause
:room
cls
SET /P chatpublic=[everyone]
SET "
echo %name%: %chatpublic%    |%D%|>> room.txt
pause
goto room
```

[without the launcher photo](http://postimg.org/gallery/3al1m4ace/)

Comment: The least you could do is show us your code and tell us the error u get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the culprit:

```
echo %name%: %chatpublic%    |%D%|>> room.txt
```

That's because the `|` vertical line has a special meaning in Windows command line interpreter: `commandA  |  commandB`: [pipe the output from `commandA` into `commandB`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

If you do want use a `|` vertical line in another sense (e.g. display it with an `echo` command), then you should [escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) it as follows:

```
echo %name%: %chatpublic%    ^|%D%^|>> room.txt
```